# Email being replied to receiver instead of sender or the reply-to address

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs-api, gmail-api

I have written a Google apps script to send email notification for the contact form on my website.

here is the code I used to send the notification email to my inbox

```
GmailApp.sendEmail("myemail@mydomain.com", "subject", "some message", {
    name: "Site Admin",
    from: "siteEmail@website.com",
    replyTo: "userEmail@domain.com"
});
```

this code sends an email to `myemail@mydomain.com` and the email headers are set as expected

here is the sample of original message

```
Delivered-To: myemail@mydomain.com
Received: by 10.60.42.99 with SMTP id n3cs47090oel;
          Thu, 21 Aug 2014 20:48:02 -0700 (PDT)
DKIM-Signature: ...
X-Google-DKIM-Signature: ...
MIME-Version: 1.0
X-Received: by 10.42.58.138 with SMTP id i10mr532439ich.18.140234282395;
            Thu, 21 Aug 2014 20:48:02 -0700 (PDT)
Reply-To: userEmail@domain.com
Message-ID: <20cf30334123125012fb42a@google.com>
Date: Fri, 22 Aug 2014 03:48:02 +0000
Subject: New message from User (userEmail@domain.com)
From: "Site Admin" <siteEmail@website.com>
To: myemail@mydomain.com
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1; format=flowed; delsp=yes

some message
```

the problem occurs when I click reply to this message from my inbox and it takes `myemail@mydomain.com` as the recipient instead of the expected `userEmail@domain.com`  (the Reply-To address) or even `siteEmail@website.com` (the From or the sender's) address.

here is the link for the reference of api used in the code in question [GmailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, options)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String,Object))

Please help me understand what am I missing here? Why the reply is sent to the incorrect recipient?

**Update**

I just notice that if I reply via mobile app, the reply-to address is being used as the recipient address. This is the expected behavior.

This is bit wired to have different behavior of gmail in these scenarios. The web interface chooses myemail whereas the mobile app chooses the expected reply-to address for the reply of same email.

Does it mean that there could be a potential flaw in the gmail web interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Google Script code is correct, it is a problem at Gmail's end. It sometimes does not recognize the replyTo address especially when a message has been sent from Apps Script.

This is already a [pending issue](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4217) on Google Code. You can star it to highlight it and maybe they'll patch it someday.

Comment: I guess you meant "does not..." :-)  ?

Comment: Indeed the problem is exactly the same, it does not recognize the reply to address. For me it is not sometime, it happens every-time. I was wondering if there is a workaround for the same.

Comment: Thank you for the investigation, that make sense to understand the issue. BTW did you see the `Update` in the question, I notice that it worked correctly on mobile app, only web interface has the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to **pass** the `recipient` as userEmail@domain.com and if you also want to receive the copy of the same you can use **Advanced parameters** `bcc` as myemail@mydomain.com because recipient is the **the addresses of the recipient** and thus it turns automatically to reply to when u click reply ...

Hope this helps!!

Comment: I can not set the the recipient as users email as it would deliver the notification to the user's inbox instead of my inbox. I guess you wanted to suggest to modify the from address as the as users email, but that is also not possible due to gmail's restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

replyTo has always been worked perfectly for me with zero errors. I am not so sure about this issue. But is there really a parameter ***"from: "siteEmail@website.com"*** in MailApp.

I dont see such one in the MailApp documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app).
Please try your codes by removing ***from:***

```
GmailApp.sendEmail("myemail@mydomain.com", "subject", "some message", {
name: "Site Admin",
replyTo: "userEmail@domain.com"
```

});

Comment: the one I am using is [GmailApp.sendEmail](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String,Object)), I'll give a try using MailApp. thanks for your effort.